# Decompile an imported module (e.g. with uncompyle2)

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

my task is to export an imported (compiled) module loaded from a container.

I have a Py.-Script importing a module. Upon using print(module1) I can see that it is a compiled python (pyc) file, loaded from an archive. As I cannot access the archive, my idea was to import the module and have it decompiled with uncompyle2.

This is my minimum code:

```
import os, sys
import uncompyle2
import module1
with open("module1.py", "wb") as fileobj:
uncompyle2.uncompyle_file(module1, fileobj)
```

However, this prints my an error. If I substitute module1 in the uncompyle argument with the actual path, it does not make a difference. I tried the code snippet successfully when the pyc-file not loaded from a container but rather a single file in a directory and it worked.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\....\run.py", line 64, in <module>
  uncompyle2.uncompyle_file(module1, fileobj)
File "C:\....\Python\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\uncompyle2\__init__.py", line 124, in uncompyle_file
  version, co = _load_module(filename)
File "C:\.....\Python\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\uncompyle2\__init__.py", line 67, in _load_module
  fp = open(filename, 'rb')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, module found
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going wrong with your initial assumption:

> As I cannot access the archive, my idea was to import the module and
>   have it decompiled with uncompyle2.

Uncompiling an already loaded module is unfortunately not possible. A loaded Python module is not a mirror of the on-disk representation of a `.pyc` file. Instead, it is a collection of *objects* created as a side effect of executing the code in the `.pyc`. Once the code has been executed, its byte code is discarded and it (in the general case) cannot be reconstructed.

As an example, consider the following Python module:

```
import gtk
w = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
w.add(gtk.Label("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"))
w.show_all()
```

Importing this module inside an application that happens to run a [GTK main loop](http://www.gtk.org/) will pop up a window with some text as a side effect. The module will have a dict with two entries, `gtk` pointing to the `gtk` module, and `w` pointing to an already created GTK window. There is no hint there how to create *another* GTK window of the sort, nor how to create another such module. (Remember that the object created might have been arbitrarily complex and that its creation could be a very involved process.)

You might ask, then, if that is so, then what is the content of the `pyc` file? How did it get loaded the first time? The answer is that the `pyc` file contains an on-disk rendition of the byte-compiled code in the module, ready for execution. Creating a `pyc` file is roughly equivalent to doing something like:

```
import marshal
def make_pyc(source_code, filename):
    compiled = compile(source_code, filename, "exec")
    serialized = marshal.dumps(compiled)
    with open(filename, "wb") as out:
        out.write(serialized)

# for example:
make_pyc("import gtk\nw = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)...",
         "somefile.pyc", "exec")
```

On the other hand, loading a compiled module is approximately equivalent to:

```
import sys, marshal, imp
def load_pyc(modname):
    with open(modname + ".pyc", "rb") as in_:
        serialized = in_.read()
    compiled = marshal.loads(serialized)
    module = sys.modules[modname] = imp.new_module(modname)
    exec compiled in module.__dict__

load_pyc("somefile")
```

Note how, once the code has been executed with the `exec` statement, the string and deserialized bytecode is no longer used and will be swept up by the garbage collector. The only remaining effect of the `pyc` having been loaded is the presence of a new module with living functions, classes, and other objects that are impossible to serialize, such as references to open files, network connections, OpenGL canvases, or GTK windows.

What modules like `uncompyle2` do is the inverse of the `compile` function. You must have the actual *code* of the module (either serialized as in a `pyc` file or deserialized code object as in the `compiled` variable in the snippets above), from which `uncompyle2` will produce a fairly faithful representation of the original source.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate and complete answer. I learnt a lot!  However, I guess there must be another way. I just have to find another way to access to file then, other then importing. Any suggestion on which direction to look is highly appreciated.

Comment: @lammy How is the file imported? Where is the archive located and what are its contents?

Comment: Hej User. The file is imported using the zipimport module and then loaded using "import ... from".. However, I cannot open the file with any typical compression software. The File command on Linux and TrID only see raw data. I am not sure how to proceed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @lammy Interesting riddle. I will try to tackle it tomorrow when I get back home.

Comment: @ user4815162342 Okay, you understand why this keeps me occupied. I am trying to investigate if the zipimport routine has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

pass the filename *string* first and then the file object to write to:

```
with open("out.txt","w") as f:
    uncompyle2.uncompyle_file('path_to.pyc',f)
```

You can see the output:

```
with open("/home/padraic/test.pyc","rb") as f:
    print(f.read())
with open("out.txt","r+") as f:
    uncompyle2.uncompyle_file('/home/padraic/test.pyc',f)
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
�
d�ZdS(cCs   dGHdS(Nshello world((((stest.pytfoosN(R(((stest.pyt<module>s

#Embedded file name: test.py


def foo():
    print 'hello world'
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested with xpath = module1.__file__


with open("out.txt","w") as f:
    uncompyle2.uncompyle_file(xpath,f)  but oddly when running i get IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\.....\\modul1.enc\\modul1\\modul1.pyc'

Comment: @lammy, you are passing a `.pyc` file yes?

Comment: @Padauc Cunningham. When I use print modul1.__file__ it shows me the path to the pyc file as above.

Comment: well your error is not related to uncompyle2,  pass the path explicitly and make sure you either escape the backslashes , use raw string `r` or use  `/` in your path.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to pass an already loaded module to `uncompyle2`. While this would be a reasonable thing to do in C, where a loaded object file is not that different from an on-disk object file, it doesn't work in Python. I posted an answer that explains this in some detail.